# Finding the maximum from a two dimensional list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a two-dimensional list where each value of $ x $ can have many values of $ y $. for example

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}}
```

For each value of $ x $, I have to find out the maximum value of $ y $. So, the result will be like

```
{{1, 4}, {2, 5}}
```

I tried with `Max`, `Short` but was not able to run this in the loop.

Is there an efficient method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `GroupBy` and `MaximalBy`

```
gpLst = GroupBy[lst, First, MaximalBy[#, Last][[1]] &]
```

> <|1 -> {{1, 4}}, 2 -> {{2, 5}}|>

```
gpLst//Values
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 5}}

Comment: Thanks @Anjan. It worked.

Answer (score 6):

Another one:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}};
GroupBy[data, First -> Last, Max]
```

> <|1 -> 4, 2 -> 5|>

If you need the result as a list of pairs:

```
KeyValueMap[List, %]
```

> {{1, 4}, {2, 5}}

Comment: Yes, it also worked. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since you specified "Is there an efficient method?"

```
GatherBy[Sort@list, First][[All, -1]]
```

(here `list` is your list or variable the list is assigned to).

This should outperform the accepted solution by at least an order of magnitude.

Slightly more verbose, but even quicker:

```
With[{g = GatherBy[list, First]}, 
 Transpose[{g[[All, 1, 1]], Max /@ g[[All, All, 2]]}]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation of @sjoerd's answer:

```
data={{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{2,2},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5}};

ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][data[[All,2]],data[[All,1]],Max]
```

> <|1 -> 4, 2 -> 5|>

For large datasets, this will be much faster than [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy):

```
data = RandomInteger[10000, {10^6, 2}];
r1=ResourceFunction["GroupByList"][data[[All,2]], data[[All,1]], Max];//AbsoluteTiming
r2=GroupBy[data, First->Last, Max];//AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.10384, Null}

> {0.514609, Null}

> True

This approach is also slightly faster than @ciao's.

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}};
MaximalBy[#, Last] & /@ Split[list, #1[[1]] == #2[[1]] &]
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar in spirit to [Sjoerd Smit's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228170/46581): the wonderful thing about Mathematica's *associations* is that they automatically override earlier values in favor of later ones, which is exactly what you want! To demonstrate, let me shuffle your input:

```
data = {{1, 2}, {1, 4}, {2, 2}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {1, 3}, {2, 3}}
```

Converting into an association only keeps the last occurrence of each first coordinate:

```
AssociationThread @@ Transpose@data
```

returns `<|1 -> 3, 2 -> 3|>`. So we just need to sort first (fortunately `Sort` automatically checks second coordinates after it checks first coordinates):

```
AssociationThread @@ Transpose@Sort@data
```

returns `<|1 -> 4, 2 -> 5|>`. And if you want the answer as ordered pairs again, there's a function that does that:

```
KeyValueMap[List, AssociationThread @@ Transpose@Sort@data]
```

returns `{{1, 4}, {2, 5}}`.

Comment: Thank you @Greg